Shortest side of triangle
What is the shortest side of a triangle whose internal angle measures are in the ratio 2 : 5 : 8,
and the perimeter 48 cm?
I calculated the angle measures, a + b + c = 48 and sine law but i don't know what to do next.

I gave a wrong answer thinking of sides not angles! So Ideleted it.

You can find the angles as 24,96,60, use law of sines and find side lengths

To expand upon @whatamidoing comment, the angles ($A, B,C$) are in the ratio $2:5:8$. So we can say for some $k$,
$$A = 2k, B = 5k, C = 8k$$
We also know the sum of angles in a triangle,
$$A + B + C = 180$$
You can solve the above equations for $k$, and then get the angles. Next, sine rule tells us
$$\frac{\sin A}{a} = \frac{\sin B}{b} = \frac{\sin C}{c}$$
Rearranging, we can say for some $p$,
$$a = p \sin A, b = p \sin B, c = p \sin C$$
And we also know the sum of sides,
$$a + b + c = 48$$
So again, solving the above you can get $p$, after which you can calculate the sides.
